# Set Value for ace editor without selecting the whole editor

Tags: ace-editor

So you can set value of an ace editor with `setValue` but after setting the value, the editor will select the whole value of the editor. How do you disable this? This mean when I set value of ace editor to `Hello world`, it won't highlight `Hello world`

Answer (score 180, accepted):

You can use the second parameter to control cursor position after setValue

```
editor.setValue(str, -1) // moves cursor to the start
editor.setValue(str, 1) // moves cursor to the end
```

Comment: This answer is now obsolete. Ace has changed since 2013. See Danial's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65754932/8910547

Comment: This is still correct in 2022 !!!

Answer (score 17):

You can even use clearSelection() after you do an setValue();

```
editor.setValue("Hello World");
editor.clearSelection(); // This will remove the highlight over the text
```

Comment: This is not the proper way to set the editor content anymore. See Danial's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65754932/8910547

Comment: @Inigo How come it is not a proper way? [Ace's own documentation](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=howto) still has `editor.setValue()` as the first option for setting editor content.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure if editor.setValue() is a remnant from the old days or what, but the proper way to set an editor's content is

```
editor.session.setValue(text);
```

or

```
editor.getSession().setValue(text);
```

This will NOT select the text, so there's no need to do any of the things mentioned on this page.

editor.setValue() explicitly selects all (and forgets to unselect it); but there's no reason to use it.

Comment: Well, [Ace's own documentation](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=howto) still says to use `editor.setValue()` to set content. And it also says to use `editor.getSession().setValue()` to set a value and reset undo history, but that's about it.

Comment: Docs are best laid plans. The truth is that editor.setValue() is a function that calls session.setValue() and does a bunch of other stuff. The session function is the raw function

Answer (score 9):

This works for me!

```
editor.setValue(editor.getValue(), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var prevtext = $("#editor").val();
 prevtext = prevtext + "<br/>";
 $("#editor").val(prevtext).blur();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been having your same issue.

Even though you can set the second parameter to either **1** or **-1**, I think you should also check this: https://ace.c9.io/api/editor.html#Editor.setValue

```
Editor.setWrapBehavioursEnabled(Boolean enabled)
```

Use this right after creating the editor.

This works very well for me.
The difference between this method and the one shared by [a user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18629202/5153829) is that the caret's position is not changed, you can move it yourself using `Editor.selection.moveTo(row, column)`, this way the user won't experience weird caret position changes when using, say, CTRL+Z to undo an action :)

Comment: This answer is not clear, do you mean that calling `Editor.setWrapBehavioursEnabled(Boolean enabled)` with some value just after the editor is initialized will prevent all text from being selected when calling `editor.setValue`?