# ACE Editor -> Loaded script is highlighted by default

Tags: ace-editor

I am loading script into the Ace editor, and upon render, the entire script is highlighted as if someone did a ctrl+a (select all).  How do make the contents "unselected" ... seems like it should work that way by default.

Based on documentation, it seems like I could workaround with:

```
session.getSelection().clearSelection();
```

... and based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614169/set-value-for-ace-editor-without-selecting-the-whole-editor), it seems I could also do this:

```
editor.setValue(str, -1) // moves cursor to the start
editor.setValue(str, 1) // moves cursor to the end
```

Neither work...

Comment: could you make a jsbin demo reproducing the problem, it seems to work fine http://jsbin.com/ojijeb/180/edit

Comment: Yes I will, and thanks for the post.  My context is ace plus ace-ui angular module, plus a directive wrapping that.  So seeing that it works, I will probably find the solution in breaking this down to the bare elements.  Stay tuned.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to remove some of the following, it's hard to say without seeing your code, but this should definitely cover it.

```
editor.setValue('hello world');
editor.clearSelection(1);
editor.gotoLine(1);
editor.getSession().setScrollTop(1);
editor.blur();
editor.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I worked around it this way

```
editor.once('focus', function(){
  editor.selection.clearSelection()
})
```

So it seems that in some cases the editor is not ready yet to accept the command.